# How to use "hardcoded" scopes in backend lists

Tags: octobercms

I'd like to display a list of records in 2 separate tabs. 
For example, lets take invoices. In the first tab, there should be records with `status="paid"` and in the second tab with `status="new"`

I know I can create the tabs in the controllers index view and use different list definitions but I cant figure out how to force a scope on a list definition.

The same thing can be done in the realation config file by using the `conditions` options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the listExtendQuery function in the controller, about like this

```
public $listConfig = ['status_paid' => 'config_paid_list.yaml', 'status_new' => 'config_new_list.yaml'];

...

public function listExtendQuery($query, $definition = null) {
    if ($definition == 'status_paid') {
        $query->where('status', 'paid');
    } elseif ($definition == 'status_new') {
        $query->where('status', 'new');
    }
}
```